# Can't retrieve rss xml information from other websites using Axios and Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, rss, axios

I have multiple websites that have RSS XML feed, and I want to use it for my Web App. I tried using Axios function (showed below).

```
axios.get('https://www.15min.lt/rss/sportas')
     .then((response) => {
          loading = false;
          this.dataReceived = response;
          console.log(response);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
          loading = false;
          this.errorReceived = error;
          console.log({ error });
     });
```

But all I got back is

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to upload all project to the server because I found out that this error can be caused because of using it locally on the personal machine. But the result I got is the same, except instead of 'null' in error, I got my domain name.

I tried other Web App based on Vue.js to test or it's my side problem or website is just blocking any connection to RSS feed. But http://qreader.qcode.in web app worked with my links, and I'm sure it's possible to make it work. But I don't have an answer how to make it work.

In my project, I'm using Vue.js, Axios, and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the easiest way myself. There is a website - https://cors.now.sh which helps to make these requests.

Just use it like in the example below:

```
XML Retrieve URL - https://cors.now.sh/https://example.com/rss-xml-link
```